# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.myObj'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The below code is working fine. Every time `props.myObj["test"]?.prop1?.data` changes it triggers the `useEffect`'s function.
However, I am getting a warning `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.myObj'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

I cannot include it in the dependencies array since it is gonna cause an infinite loop (since `props.myObj` has nested objects that changes continually).
And of course I cannot remove the current dependency. So any idea how to fix this?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const data = props.myObj["test"]?.prop1?.data || {};
    if (data["first"]) {
        setTotalData(data["first"].data.length);
    }
}, [props.myObj["test"]?.prop1?.data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `"test"` is a constant, then do the following instead.

```js
const data = props.myObj.test?.prop1?.data || {};
```

If not, then you are using the `useEffect` hook wrong, because the variables in the dependency list are supposed to be constant in terms of reference.

Comment: test is not a constant

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the last(previous) `totalData` and if previous `totalData` (i.e.data `["first"].data.length`) is different than new then only do `setTotalData`. Otherwise if that changes everytime then you will have infinite loop. But looks like you are calculating some value based to props. This can be made as computed value using `useMemo`.

```
const totalData = React.useMemo(props.myObj?.test?.prop1?.data?.first ?  data?.first?.data?.length : 0,[props.myObj])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the warning:

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

It's still a good practice to do it like this.